# How to change the background color of a single page in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, microsoft-word-2010

I can easily change the page color of every pages in my document thanks to the Page Layout Tab in the Ribbon, but I would like to change the color of a single page.

Any idea about how to to this with Word 2010 ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Word has no option to change color of individual pages in a document. Since it is hardcoded in the program, there is no way to change this behavior (page color always applies to whole document).

However, there is a workaround. If you cover the page with a text box and fill the text box with whatever color you want, you can have individually colored pages. This is not a productive method but the only one I can suggest.

Answer (score 36):

Create a specific section for your page, then use the header/footer to insert a full-page rectangle with your specific color.

Mark the checkbox "different first page"

Comment: This is creative and clean solution

Answer (score 8):

Insert a shape (square). Drag it by its handles to fit the extremities of the page. Choose 'Behind text' in Wrap Text. Tint it in 'Fill' menu. This will print just for this page.

Answer (score 2):

Create a seperate document titled "Cover Page...(your document title)".  This way they save together in the document folder.  So dumb that in 2010 they still can't create different cover page color as has been requested for years, but this work around is so much easier than other options I have heard.

Bonus?  You get to view side-by-side with your document when creating your table of contents (if you have one).

Answer (score 1):

Create separate documents for each set of differently colored pages.  For each set of pages, change the background color.  Change all separate documents into .pdfs.  Then merge the documents into a single .pdf.  Each section will have its own page color

Comment: Although you have a good suggestion how to do this, this question was how to do it in Word 2010.

Comment: I believe I understand the reason for this answer -- many people are intending to use word to create pdfs for publishing. So this is handy as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Word 2007

1. Draw a box (Insert -> Shapes ...select the rectangle)
2. Set the box's colour (Format -> Shape Fill)
3. Put the box behind the text (Format -> Send to Back -> Send behind text)
4. Resize the box to fill the page (drag the handles)
5. On a different page set the background colour for the rest of the document (Page Layout -> Page Color)

This avoids having text within a text box, yet enables individual page colours to be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the background color of just one page.  The background color applies to the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done properly, but if you go on images and type in the color you want, copy it, then paste it, and right click on it and press wrap text: then press wrap behind text, that will work.Then just make it fill the whole page. You can also do the near same thing by going on insert, then pictures, then choosing your picture. Right click on it and click wrap text, then behind text. Stretch out the picture until it fills the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word 2007 and Microsoft Windows 7 it is quite easy to do. If you have already printed the page you want coloured, draw a 'text box' to cover the whole page and click on the 'fill' colour you want. Stretch the box to completely fill the page, then go to 'Text Wrapping' and click on 'behind text'. This gives you your single coloured page.

Once you print it, it will say you are outside the printable area - ignore this and it should print the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

go to tools then to merge documents then individual coloured pages than customise

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  Highlight the words on the page then hit the color fill and select your color you prefer.  You can color one page and not the others.  What a beautiful sight.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2010:
- Insert/Shapes: Click the rectangular shape 
- Draw the it in the page you want to change color
- Fill the rectangular with the color you want
- Format/Text Wrapping/In Front of Text
- Drag and enlarge the rectangular to the whole page

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You need to put your background in the header of each page and strech. Once you do that then creat a new section and repeat every time you want to change the background

Answer (score 0):

I use Microsoft Word 2010 and I simply insert a cover page at the top of the document from the Insert tab. I then choose the preset cover page sample called 'Perspective' which has a gradient background. I remove/change the mountain picture as required and change the colour of the gradient or change it into a solid fill, use a pattern, texture or even picture backgrounds as usual. Remember to do this on the document you are actually working on. You will not be able insert any pages that you have been working on as separate document. 
If you want to insert different coloured pages in between, then you can try setting the page margins to 'narrow' from the page layout tab and then simply draw a rectangle or insert a coloured text box that is as big as the borders and then choose 'send backward'--> 'send behind text' from the format tab. 
Alternatively, if you are not forced to use Word, you could try using Publisher instead, which would definitely make life so much easier on this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

This a bit of an advanced method but super effective and requires the use of "**InDesign**" if you want to go the extra mile and you're allowed to Submit in a **.PDF** format.

**1**.Create your first color page (save it as **PDF**)

**2**.create your second color page (do the same)

**3**.Open **Indesign** and place the pages accordingly.

**Bonus**: You can even make it look either like a normal page by page paper or a magazine-like paper!

Comment: The question asks about doing it in Word 2010.  This is really the answer to a different question.  Consider asking a new question about how to do this for PDF and provide this answer (that Q&A format is allowed on the site).

Answer (score 0):

We can use a rectangular shape and fill it with the color, or we can create a black picture in paint, and then can place it in word... remember to use 'send to background' after right clicking it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

First of all you cannot apply page colour to one separate page using the 'Page Color' option on the 'Design' tab.

However, there is one simple procedure to apply color for a single page using text box, which is explained in the following procedure:

1. Go to a page for which you wish to apply page color.
2. On the **Insert** menu, click **Text Box** > **Draw Text Box**.
3. Select the text box, go to **Shape Fill** and select the color you wish to apply for the page.
4. Select the text box, click **Shape Outline**> **No Outline**. Once this step has been followed, outline of the text box disappears.
5. Now drag this text box till the edge of page. Make sure you have dragged the
6. Again select the text box, select **Wrap Text** > **Behind Text**.
7. Now the page color has been applied to the required page.