# Bring header/footer in front of object

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

As the accepted answer of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/203541/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-single-page-in-word-2010) say, I covered the page with a text box to change the color of specific pages. I set wrap text attribute to behind text. The problem is the page number in the footer isn't displayed.

Is there any workaround so that the page number can be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the text box in the header/footer and follow the same steps. To prevent the textbox from being repeated on every page you will need to insert a section break at the end of that page (in the body of the document, not the header and footer) and unlink the headers and footers in the new section. A short tutorial on how to do this is available [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103481/how-to-use-multiple-headers-and-footers-in-a-single-document/).

Comment: Thanks. But when I cut-paste the text box in the footer, it appears in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide the answer to my slightly different situation, just in case anyone else arrives here looking for that answer:

I had a text box in the margin, with word-wrapping enabled, and was experiencing the peculiar issue that when the top of the text box was even with the top of the top paragraph, an area of white would obscure most of the header, but not all of it, as though there were ANOTHER text box (which was actually completely non-existent), on top of the header, obscuring it. If I moved the text box down so that one line of text extended to the margin above it, the header reappeared in full. If I moved the text box up to just slightly above the top of the leading paragraph, the header would return in full (I figured that out after arriving here looking for help).

The issue turned out to be paragraph spacing of the adjoining paragraph. The paragraph was set to have space before the paragraph (12 pt), and when set to zero, the invisible area obscuring the header also went away, so that the header is visible, no matter where I place the text box.