# How do I remove the colored area on top of a docx file?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, colors, styles, headers

I am using Office Word 2016.

There is a colored area on top of every page for a docx file and I'm trying to remove it but couldn't.

Here is the download link for that file, it's a resume template.
https://www.coolfreecv.com/doc/coolfreecv_resume_en_06.doc

Please note that it is for a doc, I converted it to docx when editing.

I want to have only the first page featuring that colored area and nothing more. All other pages should be without this area but should retain the colored area at the bottom.

Comment: Did you try to double click the area? You're likely talking about the header of a page. Maybe consider including a screenshot (you can upload it e.g. on imgur.com).

Comment: @Seth There's a link for that file I'm talking about. Kindly download it and check it our for yourself.

Comment: It's not about whenever I can download a file or not. The file may be moved, removed or in other ways change which would invalidate this question. With a screenshot even than someone could try to understand what the context of the question is and whenever it applies to his problem. Nice that you did get an answer that solves your question.

Comment: I downloaded the file.  I don't have Word 2016, but I opened it in a compatible office suite.  I don't see a colored area at the top.  I do see an outline of some boxes that appear to be perhaps a table or text boxes.  Can you add a screenshot so readers will know what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove or add the colour to your pages, click "**Design**" and then "**Page Color**". Your document has been modified with "**Fill Effects**".

[image][image]

If you wanted to colour the whole page with 1 colour only, you could just click on any colour or click "**More colors ...**" To remove it completely, click "**No Color**".

As for having the colours on one page only, I think there's still no option to do that. You can check this discussion here, although it's more than 8 years old: [How to change the background color of a single page in Word 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/203541/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-single-page-in-word-2010)

You could play around with inserting a background image on the first page instead, or creating 2 different word documents (one with the colours and one without) and merge them later with Adobe Acrobat - that's what I do sometimes but it takes more time and effort (this way you can have both .pdf or .doc/x formats in the end).

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank you. Answer chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove a background image or watermark

- On the **Design** tab, click **Watermark**.
- Choose **No watermark**.

[Add, change, or delete the background of a document](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-change-or-delete-the-background-of-a-document-08782ea3-086c-4778-94bb-2ea3d187f83e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Doesn't work, and it's not an answer for word 2016. Did you download the doc file @ the link that I included in the original question?

Comment: @JohnDoe *Did you download the doc file* Yes. I have downloaded it and have successfully removed blue colored area. I have Office 2010 Rus. Looking the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1455726/910710) of [Gašper Čefarin](https://superuser.com/users/991390/ga%c5%a1per-%c4%8cefarin) I think I point you to wrong paragraph after switching the doc language manually from ru-ru to en-us by the link provided.

Comment: Hey no problem. Thanks anyway.